# Can't find Edit of Terminal on Ubuntu

Tags: terminal

I just found that I can't find the Edit option of gnome-terminal when I launch it on my Ubuntu(unity) OS, and I had got access to the Edit on the top bar to change the fonts of terminal, but now when I move cursor to the top bar, there is nothing except a "Terminal" title.

What should I do to edit my terminal preferences?

I am sorry that I am not so familiar with Ubuntu so that I don't know what more information should I provide, if it's necessary, please notify me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @EatÅPeach Sorry about that, but it is alrady answered, so I can only remember it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over any section of the terminal and right click then a list of options will appear. One of these options is profiles, hover over this and click preferences to bring up a number of options that you can configure to your liking.

Comment: Of course I will, but I can only accept it after 6 minutes.